# Unexpected token : in jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, instagram-api

I'm trying to make a simple request to instagram as follows:

```js
$.getJSON("https://www.instagram.com/kidsfromthe90sband/media/?callback=?",
  function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FPhcr/731/

However it says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in the console, but the uri is ok and it works if I, for example, run it in Postman or directly in the browser. I've searched other questions but I cannot get to know my error.
Thank you.

EDIT

If I don't put a callback=? there's another error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: It is not a right way to request instagram's api, you should have a look at instagram's developer docs

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Actually when you are using any social app data like for  facebook,linkedin or instagram in your case etc you need to register your app there so you get unique token  & id which help them to authenticate you.So,they can fullfill your request through their provided public API .

Its happening because as per JSONP the result /responce should be wrapped inside callback which is not happening in this case.

EDIT :

you need to subscribe to instagram after which you get your ACCESS-TOKEN.

then form url like this one

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/coffee/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&callback=callbackFunction
```

which will give jsonp.

Please refer here for more

1. [devloper](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)
2. [endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

Comment: so, how should I make the call to make it work? If I don't put a callback=?'there's another error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: Its a server side implentation

Comment: I think you need ACCESS_TOKEN of instagram API then try with this one

Comment: I know of the need of an ACCESS_TOKEN for certain calls. But, as I've said, this one does not, as I can access it from the browser or Postman. I'd like to know a way to make it work or an explanation of why it cannot work. Thank you.

Comment: Hi RYAJ, I have accepted your answer as it works, however it did not work for the endpoint I was asking for (I wanted to make it work without the need of an access_token). Thank you anyway.

Comment: Actually when you are using any social app data like for  facebook,linkedin or instagram in your case etc you need to register your app there so you get unique token  & id which help them to authenticate you.So,they can fullfill your request.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating the API as if it would return JSONP data, but it does not. So jQuery then tries to evaluate the pure JSON return as JSONP and logs the error.

You have to find the correct API endpoint for JSONP, there is a documentation that can be found here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/.